# Interactive share through JS not rendering

Tags: javascript, google-plus

Can someone explain to me why the following code isn't working? I have copied the code from Google and I need the "onshare" facility which I don't believe is available through the standard HTML. There are no JS errors - and nothing renedered:

```
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
                    <head>
                            <title>Title of the document</title>
                            <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
                    </head>
            <body>
            <h1 style="font-family:arial;font-size:15px;">google_test</h1>                        <div id="sharePost"></div>
                    <script>
                      var options = {
                            contenturl: 'https://plus.google.com/pages/',
                            contentdeeplinkid: '/pages',
                            clientid: 'YOUR ID HERE',
                            cookiepolicy: 'single_host_origin',
                            prefilltext: 'Create your Google+ Page too!',
                            calltoactionlabel: 'CREATE',
                            calltoactionurl: 'http://plus.google.com/pages/create',
                            calltoactiondeeplinkid: '/pages/create',
                            onshare: function(response){
                                    alert(response); 
                            }                                
                      };

                      gapi.interactivepost.render('sharePost', options);
                    </script>
                    </body>
                    </html>
```

After some investigation (5/1/15) I discovered that in the response (net panel in firebug) I was getting an error back in a hidden text box. This was because my origin url was wrong, but now I get the following:

```
<input type="hidden" id="error" value="true" />
<input type="hidden" id="response-form-encoded" value="state=887621045%7C0.2365188186&amp;error=immediate_failed&amp;num_sessions=1&amp;session_state=MY_SESSION_ID" />
```

Any idea what this might mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is so simple - thanks to http://wheresgus.com/iodemos/demotargetipost/ for helping me see it. In the example above,

```
<div id="sharePost"></div>
```

Simply needs a content such as this:

```
<div id="sharePost"><button>hello world</button></div>
```

In fact you don't even need the button!! Why on earth the documentation doesn't have this I don't know - so have reported the documentation as not being great. Additionally you should note that the callbackurl and calltoactionurl both need the same protocols - again their examples differ.

Answer (score 0):

You load Google api with async defer. Therefore it is not ready when you create the share link.

Either you should render the share link only after the page is loaded ( using the domready event ), or remove the 'async defer' attributes.

Comment: Removed the async defer and nothing I'm afraid.